# uninitialized constant error when refactoring routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm trying to refactor my routes file using namespace. When I try to access the routes I get the error `uninitialized constant Web::Admins`.

### routes.rb : old version

```
scope path: '/web' do
     ...
     get 'admins/new' => 'web/admins#new', defaults: { format: :html }, as: :new_web_admins
     get 'admins' => 'web/admins#index', defaults: { format: :html }, as: :web_admins
     get 'admins/:id' => 'web/admins#show', defaults: { format: :html }, as: :show_web_admins
     post 'admins' => 'web/admins#create', defaults: { foramt: :html }, as: :create_web_admins
     patch 'admins/:id/edit' => 'web/admins#update', defaults: { format: :html }, as: :edit_web_admins
     delete 'admins/:id' => 'web/admins#destroy', defaults: { format: :html }, as: :destroy_web_admins
     ...
```

### routes.rb : refactored

```
namespace :web do
    namespace :admins do
      get 'new' => 'web/admins#new', defaults: { format: :html }#, as: :new_web_admins
      get '/' => 'web/admins#index', defaults: { format: :html }#, as: :web_admins
      get '/:id' => 'web/admins#show', defaults: { format: :html }#, as: :show_web_admins
      post '/' => 'web/admins#create', defaults: { foramt: :html }#, as: :create_web_admins
      patch '/:id/edit' => 'web/admins#update', defaults: { format: :html }#, as: :edit_web_admins
      delete '/:id' => 'web/admins#destroy', defaults: { format: :html }#, as: :destroy_web_admins
      post 'doit' => 'web/admins#doit', defaults: { format: :html }
    end
  end
```

#### app/controllers/web/admins_controller.rb

```
class Web::AdminsController
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`namespace :admins` expects a route like `/web/admins/` so it looks for `Web::Admins::...`

By the way consider looking into RESTful routes. By their standard you could just write:

```
namespace :web do
  resources :admins
end
```